# Can I install software with 64 in it to a computer which is 32 bit?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install "ubuntu-22.04.2-desktop-amd**64**" to my Dell Inspiron 530 which is **32**-bit.
Is this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: *amd64* is a different architecture to *i386*.   A machine that is *amd64* can also use *i386*, but the reverse is not possible, ie. *i386* will not run *amd64*.

Comment: You've have to check what *architecture* your machine actually uses; as a quick look shows that *amd64* was available for Dell Inspiron 530.  Be aware that if the machine had windows on it when sold; hardware that was *amd64* was often sold with 32-bit windows as it was $5 cheaper; and consumers understood $5 far more than 32 vs 64 bits. If the Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop boots (*beyond just try/install page as that can show on i386 hardware too*) then your machine is *amd64*.  I'd likely recommend a lighter *flavor* on intel Core2duo type hardware.

Comment: I don't know your machine, but an example of a machine I used in QA (*Quality Assurance*) is `dell latitude d610 (pentium m, 1.5gb, intel i915)` which being pentium M is 32-bit or x86 (*i386 in Debian/Ubuntu terms*) only, and the latest ISO I could boot & install was Lubuntu/Xubuntu 19.04; however 19.04 not being an non-LTS reached EOL prior to 18.04; thus the last QA that machine was involved with was 18.04.5 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) with that release reaching EOL next month (April 2023)

Comment: Looking up online yours is a desktop, thus maybe closest I used was `hp dx6120mt (mini-tower, pentium 4 dual core, 3gb, winfast clone of nvidia 7600gt)` but it being *i386* or 32-bit only was also used up to 19.04 & last with 18.04.   Both the boxes (& numerous other x86/i386 I have) were also used in some QA of Debian; and it is what I'd install if I was installing an OS (*but it's off-topic here*), in fact most of my x86 hardware runs Debian now.